# Jquery getJSON  return old value 

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, vbscript

I want to fetch record from controller this code work fine on page ready event, but with i save new record and want to fetch list of new record, code return old record...

```
function FetchMessage(Id) {

        $("#SearchResult").empty();
        $.getJSON("/home/BusinessMessages", { busId: Id }, function (data) {

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $("#SearchResult").append('<div> <div class="nameHd">' + data[i].messagebody + '<div class="icon"><img src="../../Content/images/arrow-msg.gif" alt="" /></div></div><div class="imgBox"><img src="' + data[i].imageurl + '" alt="" /></div></div><div class="clr"></div>');
            }
            $("#record").html(data.length + " messages");
        });
    }
```

```vb
    Function BusinessMessages(ByVal busID As String) As JsonResult
        Return Json(home.GetMessageByBusId(busID),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
    End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

I am sure it is happening in IE. The reason is IE is caching the response and `getJSON` will not allow to set cache to `false`. Change your code to use `.ajax` method and set dataType to `json` and set cache to `false`.